# getAffineTransform - opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, affinetransform

Q1. I want to match points (x1, x2, x3) to points (y1, y2, y3). Does function `getAffineTransform` always return the same transformation matrix no matter what order of these points is?

Q2. If I know these points are transformed only by rotation and translation withouth any scaling, what is the easiest to remove scaling from the transformation matrix returned by `getAffineTransform`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A1, yes, the solution should be unique as long as the two sets of points are not collinear.

A2, your result matrix will be in the form:

```
[ A B C ]
[ D E F ]
```

C is your translation in x; F is your translation in y. Both are scale invariant.

If you take the left-most terms, these correspond to rotation and scale

```
[A B]
[D E]
```

in the following formula:

```
[I cos(t)  -I sin(f)]
[J sin(t) J cos (F)]
```

where I is the scale in x and J is the scale in y.

To remove scaling, divide by A and B by sqrt(A*A+B*B) and D and E by sqrt(D*D+E*E)